# Delete the x first words from a string

Tags: java, string

This function displays only as many dice as you specify in the 'amount'. Now, I want to be able to tell from where it takes the words. From where it starts to display the words. And not always from the beginning.

```
static String firstTwoWords(String s, int amount, int from) {
    int spaces = 0;
    int i;
    //from = delete the front records from the string
    for (i = 0; i < s.length() && spaces < amount; i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') spaces++;
    return s.substring(0, i);
}
```

Comment: My suggestion when you're dealing with "words" from a "sentence" is to split it up at word-boundary into a *container*. Then for example to remove "words" is easy, as it's just to remove the corresponding element from the container.

Comment: Is `from` the sitring index `for (i = from;` or the word no `spaces < amount + from`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
static String anyWords(String s, int amount, int from) {
    int spaces = 0;
    int i;
    String[] stringArray = s.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < from; j++)
        stringArray[j] = "";
    for (String value : stringArray)
        if (!Objects.equals(value, ""))
            sentence.append(value).append(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < sentence.length() && spaces < amount; i++)
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') spaces++;
    return sentence.substring(0, i);
}
```

I hope i can help

Comment: Thanks that you have already made me perfect

Answer (score 0):

I recommend in this case using this:

```
String.split(" ");
```

The split() methods splits an existing String into substings. The substrings will be stored in a String[].

**The split methods works as following:**

It takes a "Pattern" (Regex) as a Parameter, that defines where the String has to be split. So if you want to split the String "My name is John", you can use
the example above to split the String at all spaces.

The result is the String[], containing the 4 words at the first 4 indexes.

**This would look like:**

```
[0] = "My"  
[1] = "name"   
[2] = "is"   
[3] = "John"
```

So if you want to delete the first x words from a String, an easy way is to loop from index x to end and to concatenate the remaining indices with a space between them.

Comment: thanks, I already had that in mind. Now I have done it just so.